# Visual Studio 2019 all projects target file extension changed to .pyd

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have moved one of our solutions to a new system for remote development and upon opening the solution I noticed all of the projects in that solution, have different target file extension. they all have become `.pyd` regardless of the project type that is libs, DLLs, EXEs they all now have `.pyd` target extension.

I checked the solution on two other workstations and they were fine, nothing out of ordinary! but on this system I'm facing this. I have used the updated Visual Studio to no avail, so I switched back to a previous version, the same version used on the machines that had no issues. This didn't work either, I completely uninstalled Visual Studio and tried again to no avail. The problem still persists and I have no idea what is causing it or what I should be doing to rectify this.

Here is a snapshot of one of the projects, the extension looks as if it's the default:

[image]

Please note that the projects all build just fine, and there seems to be no issues regarding that.

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report to Microsoft

Comment: I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).